# Add the Post ID to the Question Summary ID in the search results listing

Tags: feature-request, search, question-lists

I'm writing a GreaseMonkey script to help me with retagging, and I need the post ID for the script. The problem is that on the [search results page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=update+panel), there is no output of the question ID in the DOM to be found.

On the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), we get `<div id="question-summary-12345678" ...>` but in the search results, all of them are `<div id="question-summary" ...>` and that's it.

My request is to please output the post ID on the search results page to match the other pages.

**Edit:** I realized this DOM is also on the user profile page, and the ID is included in there as well.

Comment: So you want to retag based on snippets?

Comment: @random: Most of the retagging I've done has been for things like `[versioncontrol]` --> `[version-control]`, where I don't even need to read the post body. Regardless, what I'm doing with the question ID isn't really the point. I think that it should be available in the DOM just like on the other pages.

Comment: ...also, the post body is visible on the edit page if I feel like it needs to be read (usually a weird combination of tags will make me read it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always scrape the question number from the hyperlink, so there is a way to accomplish this. And since the API is right around the corner (it is, right?), I don't think it's that big of a neccessity.

Comment: @balpha: Very good point. All the question links are `class`'d properly, so I could scrape the ID from the `href`. I will do that in the meantime. However, for completeness' sake, I still think my request should be taken care of, since someone else may want to do other things with that part of the DOM.

Comment: I somehow feel scraping from the URL is even better than scraping from `<div id=..>`

Comment: @Arjan: Yes, I agree with that 100% now. But I'd still like the DOM to be consistent throughout the site for other users writing scripts down the line.